# Doctrine FindBy DateTime Infinite Process

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

i have a problem when i want query a row in my mysql database.
The 'p_release_date' field is type with datetime with doctrine. and after an insert, the format is `2023-03-24 00:00:00`.

When i click on my Vue.js component, it return a date like this:

`Fri Mar 24 2023 06:05:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)`

I transform my date in PHP DateTime:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e+', $datas['date']);
$datetime->settime(0, 0);
```

Then when i made my query, the response return nothin, and i have infinite process on my network devtool:

```
$projects = $this->em->getRepository(Project::class)->findBy(['release_date' => $datetime]);
```

if someone has an issue, it will be useful.
Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

**UPDATE**

Tried to set date_default_timezone_set with Europe/Paris, but it didn't change anything.

I try to made a query with doctine on my mysql table, filter by DateTime.
Currently it return nothin and a infinite process.
I expected it returns rows.

Comment: are you using any framework? I used to have the same issue while working with InertiaJS... the only solution I found was submitting the date as string instead of a Date

Comment: Im Using Vite/Vue.js front side and Slim PHP Framwork back side.